# CSS only loads in backend

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

This works to load CSS in the backend. I'm trying to load the CSS in both the backend and the frontend though. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function load_top_bar_style() {
  wp_register_style( 'custom_top_bar_css', plugins_url( 'styles.css', __FILE__ ), false, '1.0.0' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_top_bar_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_top_bar_style' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_top_bar_style');
```

Comment: the action is `wp_enqueue_scripts`, plural

Comment: Good catch @Milo Why don't you give this as an answer?

Comment: @Milo offer it as an answer. I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *action* for adding scripts and styles is `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `scripts` is plural.

The *function* for adding a script is `wp_enqueue_script`, `script` is singular.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_top_bar_style' );
```